# Database query - not able to frame it

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, informix

Let me explain the problem statement here:

I have to pull data from 2 tables. Based on the user input, in the backend the query should first check the first table, if data is available should return and exit. If data is not available, should execute the seconds query and return the result. Can you someone help me give an example how to use if-else or CASE statement for informix?

Answer (score 1):

If the two queries return the same columns, you can express this as:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1);
```

If the columns needed from the two queries are not the same, then you should handle this at the application level -- run the first query and if nothing is returned, run the second query.  That might actually be preferable anyway, because the logic is clearer in the application.

Comment: Thank you.

Can you share some example from the application side, how you do it? I have written it already, it will be better to see some code for reference if you have any?